# Oracle DBMS Scheduler - what if database fails?

Tags: oracle, jobs

We are moving some Oracle overnight jobs off a cron server and running them via Oracle DBMS Scheduler instead. It is my understanding that if the database fails overnight then the job email notification will also fail.

Has anyone got a method of emailing users to let them know their specific overnight jobs failed in this instance (without letting them know the entire database dropped)?  It seems a slight limitation of using dbms scheduler over a cron server.

I was thinking if there was a way to monitor a gmail mailbox and if a job success email from the scheduler is not received to then send a job fail message to the users?  Couldn't see a way to do this either unfortunately.

Does anyone have any ideas for this scenario?  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your scheduler database fails, this should raise an event in your monitoring application. This is about the similar situation as compared to cron, when the server fails. In that case cron also has no way to tell it failed.

If you want to use dbms_scheduler as an enterprise scheduling tool, don't forget the reporting. Reporting should help explaining what ran and why not.